# Detect which decimal point is used in a csv file with python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-analysis, decimal-point

I was wondering if there is a way to detect which decimal point is used in csv files. I have several files I need to read, but the decimal points are sometimes European (',') and sometimes American ('.'). Is there a way to automatically detect this, so I can give it as an argument to pd.read_csv()? I'm new to programming with python but I can't seem to find the answer online.

Best regards!

Comment: [Disclaimer: I don't deal with pandas, only builtin csv module.] Csv (at least made or loaded with MS Excel) will have `;` as separator if `,` is decimal point for given locale. If you find a separator for your file, then you have decimal point as well. I don't know if there are detection methods for this, but if your file has headers, then you can peek at the first line and check what is used as csv delim there

Comment: any discoveries in this question?

Answer (score 0):

You could read the csv using `readlines`:

```py
with open('my_csv.csv', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```

You can then iterate over each line to check if `,` or `.` are more common, I would also add a check that every line has the same number of your chosen `,` `.`.

Alternatively you could add error handling to your `read_csv`. Maybe try this first.

```py
try:
    df = pd.read_csv('my_csv.csv', delimiter=',')
except:
    df = pd.read_csv('my_csv.csv', delimiter='.')
```

I would add that determining delimiters these ways are not ideal and they should really be manually interpreted.

Comment: Hi, thank for your answer. It is not the delimiter I'm looking for however, but the character to recognize as decimal point. If I use your second suggestion with dec instead of delimiter, the except statement is not executed because the try statement is valid.

Comment: In that case you could use readline(s) (you only need one line) and find which comes first as that is your decimal. If you are never encountering the except statement every row must have an identical number of ',' and '.'